# How to read facet facet_ranges in grails?

Tags: grails, solr, grails-2.0, grails-controller

```
A.<lst name="Age">
<int name="0">2</int>
<int name="2">1</int>
<int name="6">1</int>
<int name="9">1</int>
</lst>
</lst>

B.<lst name="facet_ranges">
<lst name="Age">
<lst name="counts">
<int name="0">3</int>
<int name="6">1</int>
<int name="9">1</int>
</lst>
<long name="gap">3</long>
<long name="start">0</long>
<long name="end">51</long>
</lst>
</lst>
```

i fired one RANGE query to solr database... it gives an Answer..**A and B**

But I am not able to read **B** part of answer. which is wanted to display on page
i am using grails

Help me out

thank You!!

Comment: what are you using to read the data from solr ? solr plugin ? solrj ?

Comment: i am using solrj in grails 2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check QueryResponse [getFacetRanges](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/3_6_1/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/QueryResponse.html#getFacetRanges%28%29) which should return you the range facet responses.

`getFacetRanges().get(0)` should return you [RangeFacet](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/3_6_1/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/RangeFacet.html)

RangeFacet [getCounts()](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/3_6_1/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/RangeFacet.html#getCounts%28%29) return you [RangeFacet.Count](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/3_6_1/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/RangeFacet.Count.html) which can be used to get the range and the value.

Comment: thank you for your response.. i used this getfacetranges but  i wanted to display inside value..